# How to populate RecyclerView with jsonObjectrequest

Tags: android, android-volley, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and I'm   looking how to populate RecyclerView with jsonObjectrequest.

The examples I've seen so far uses jsonArrayRequest. Please, how do I do it jsonObjectrequest.

Comment: please add your JSON response so we can see what are taking about

Comment: @humazed: any response will the ok. I just want to see a code template.

Comment: do you parsing JSON data manually or you are using some 3rd party library like Retrofit,volley etc.

Comment: @Isaac: volley library

Comment: okay, so you have created pojo for parsing, right?

Comment: @Isaac, I don't understand you.

Comment: I have used retrofit library for backend api calling and get data in JSON object and parse them in POJO(Plan old JAVA object) and than populate that data in recyclerviewadapter, so if you are looking for similar situation I can help you

Comment: @Isaac, I would prefer volley but let's see it.

Comment: Since RecyclerView are always used to populate list of data in views, that is why you haven't found any example to populate only JSONObjectRequest to the view, however I am adding an example to populate one JSONObjectRequest to the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used retrofit but I also know how volley works,I would recommend you to use retrofit over volley, since it have several benefits over volley, like :-

1. Performance is quite good
2. No need to do manual parsing
3. It have proper [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) regarding how to use library

You can [find it over here](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/) for more information.

Now, since Recycler View is generally used to populate **list of data** to the view, that is why you haven't get any example to populate one JsonObjectRequest.

However I tried to create an example in my git hub repository,to do the task you wanted to do, you can [find it over here](https://github.com/Akhilesh-Soni/android_programms/tree/master/Populate_data_to_recycler_view)

Comment: Thanks, that'a all I wanted.